# bio[message.author.id].join(" ") is not a function

Tags: javascript, github, heroku, discord.js

Since my last question, I've been trying to get it to work, but a error now occurs when I try to do the `profile` command after successfully getting the past Bio through the updated `setBio` command:

`bio[message.author.id].join is not a function`

I've begun to realize the problem, but I don't know how to properly fix it.

Here is the code around where the error happens:

```
case 'setBio':
        if(!bio[message.author.id]) {
        let messages = message.channel.messages;
                let authorMessages = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === message.author.id);
                let setBioCommands = authorMessages.filter(m => m.content.startsWith('!setBio'));
                let firstBio = setBioCommands.last();
                message.channel.send('I found a Bio you have previously set. Do you want to confirm the change to that Bio?').then(r => r.delete(10000));
            message.react('✅').then(() => message.react('❎'));
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['✅', '❎'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
                };
                message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] })
                    .then(collected => {
                        const reaction = collected.first();

                        if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
                            bio[message.author.id] = firstBio
                message.reply('Past Bio successfully restored!')
                .then(msg => msg.delete(3000));
                        }
                        else {
                            message.reply('Okey, I\'ll delete this Bio.')
                .then(msg => msg.delete(3000)); 
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(collected => {
                        message.channel.send('You didn\'t respond, so I\'ll throw this Bio into the abyss. *Buh-bye!*');
                    });
        } else {
        let newArr = args.slice(1)
        bio[message.author.id] = newArr
        message.channel.send('Your bio has been changed!')
            .then(msg => msg.delete(3000)); 
        }
        break;
        case 'profile':
        if(!bio[message.author.id]) {
        return message.channel.send('Sorry, please set a bio with `!setBio` to view your profile!')
        .then(msg => msg.delete(3000)); 
        } else {
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle('__' + message.author.username + '\'s Profile__')
            .addField(`Bio:`, bio[message.author.id].join(" ")) /// this is where the error is
            .setColor(message.member.colorRole.color)
            .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
            message.channel.send(embed);
        }
        break;
```

Comment: What is the value of bio[message.author.id]

Comment: @AkashBhandwalkar not an array :).

Comment: `join()` is an `Array` method so seems like `bio[message.author.id]` is not an array.

Comment: @AkashBhandwalkar `bio[message.author.id] = newArr`

Comment: I simply don't understand how to get this fixed.

Comment: If it's string, how can we join it again. It is already joined. It  should be instance of an Array.

Comment: If I get rid of `.join(" ")` it works but the Bio also includes `!setBio`

Comment: I added some code in the question to make it easier, the formatting may be messed up

Answer (score 1):

That error is telling you that `bio[message.author.id]` does not have a `.join()` method. `.join()` is typically used on arrays, which do have such a method. You are probably expecting `bio[message.author.id]` to be an array, but it may be some other object instead.

Try logging `bio[message.author.id]` to have a better understanding of what’s going on in the background (debugging process), and carry on from there.

Comment: I don't know how to log specifically `bio[message.author.id]` into a debugger.

Comment: Look into `console.log()`.

Comment: After testing things, I've ran into a problem since I use `winston` for console logging.